# Show auto-incremental serial number in html table

Tags: html, css, django

I have one django project. In the template html page, I use a table to demonstrate data. In the first row of the table, I want to show the ID of "i". But since the i.0 is the batch_id of the model, it does not increment from 1. How could I change the html of this page to show the serial number in first row starting from 1?

```
<table width="100" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;position:relative;left:75px;"  bordercolor="#E0E0E0">
      <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
          <th width="55px" style="word-wrap:break-word;"><div class="panel-heading">ID</div></th>
          <th width="130px" style="word-wrap:break-word;"><div class="panel-heading">Search Content</div></th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          {% for i in datas %}
           <td style="word-wrap:break-word;"><div class="panel-body"><small>{{ i.0 }}</small></div></td>
           <td style="word-wrap:break-word;color: #0066CC"><div class="panel-body"><strong><small>{{ i.2 }}</small></strong></div></td>
{% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you need a table that has multiple rows you need to change the location of "For loop" as you are looping td not tr. You need to place for loop above to the  tag and endfor should be below . For the Id related doubt can you please show me the context "datas".

Comment: By using the build-in function in template suggested by Nugora can deal with the problem, thx!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Parth Modi, your current loop just output the td.
If every set of data should be in a new row, you need to wrap the tr.

For your "serial number", I think you just talk about the loop count, starting from 1?
{{ forloop.counter }} is what you are searching for.

For more info about this, you should read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Comment: Yes, I think so.